# PHP for loop - how to escape first iteration?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, iteration

Given this PHP `for` loop

```
$row->frequency = 1;
$row->date_1 = 10000;
$row->interval = 86400;


    for ($i = 0; $i <= $row->frequency; $i++) {

        $cal_data[] = array(

            'start' => strtotime($row->date_1) + $row->interval,

            );
    }
```

I would like the first iteration of the loop to ignore the `+ $row->interval` giving me as a result:

```
10000
96400
```

I've seen this done with modulus but couldn't manage to make it work here. Anyone have suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the number `10000` valid input for `strtotime`? What are you trying to do? If you're only doing one or two things, why use a loop at all?

Comment: `10000` is just an example to simplify the question

Comment: As @sdleihssirhc suggested, 10,000 is indeed not valid - perhaps update the question with valid data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+ ($i ? $row->interval : 0)`

In other words, if `$i` is zero - first iteration - add 0 instead of `$row->interval`. This is the ternary operator, `(condition ? iftrue : iffalse)` which is roughly equivalent to an `if/else` construction except it can be used amidst a statement.

Comment: for some reason, when `$row->frequency` is for example 5, the loop generates an unexpected result => `10000, 96400, 96400, 96400, 96400` instead of incrementing for each iteration -- any idea why that's happening?

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $row->frequency; $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
          $val = strtotime($row->date_1) ;
    } else {
       $val = strtotime($row->date_1) + $row->interval;
    }
    $cal_data[] = array(

        'start' => $val

        );
}
```

Comment: thanks @scott - i think i'll go with the ternary above, its brevity seems appropriate here

Comment: similar to my comment above to @alexander, your code generates the same issue: when $row->frequency is for example 5, the loop generates an unexpected result => `10000, 96400, 96400, 96400, 96400` instead of incrementing for each iteration

Comment: That's exactly what I would expect - you're not changing $row->interval or $row->date_1.  Why would the sum change?

Comment: you're right - i wanted `$row->interval` to be incremented cumulatively as the loop goes on, for example `10000, 96400, 182800, etc` -- how can i get that?

Comment: `strtotime($row->date_1) + ($i ? ($row->interval * $i) : 0)` does what i want